# How to view member (elements) data in R?

Tags: r

I have a file containing R data.  When I load the data and display it I can see that it contains members (I don't even know if that is what these elements are called).

```
> load("irace.Rdata", data <- new.env())
> typeof(data)
[1] "environment"
> ls.str(data)
iraceResults : List of 10
 $ scenario         :List of 43
 $ irace.version    : chr "2.4.1844"
 $ parameters       :List of 10
 $ allElites        :List of 6
 $ experiments      : num [1:11, 1:3338] -9819 -6120 -1035 -9074 -9580 ...
 $ experimentLog    : num [1:24991, 1:4] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ state            :List of 14
 $ allConfigurations:'data.frame':  3338 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ softRestart      : logi [1:6] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ iterationElites  : num [1:6] 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

How do I print / show the data in these members.  For example how do I view the data in "scenario" and "allConfigurations"?  I am new to R.

Comment: Do you just want `data$scenario` and `data$allConfigurations`? That will `print()` the content of those variables in that environment.

Comment: Note what your output says, `$ allConfigurations:'data.frame':  3338 obs. of  17 variables`. Your data frame (a table) has 17 columns and 3338 rows, so it's better to do `head(data$allConfigurations)`. This prints only 6 rows and gives you an idea of the data. And `$ scenario         :List of 43` is also big.

Comment: You probably don't need to load the data into a new environment. If you just `load("irace.Rdata")` it will put the objects into the default global environment. You can see the names of everything that's in your environment with `ls()`, and you can see any individual object by typing it's name, e.g., `scenario` or `allConfigurations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$`, in R you can access the "elements" by using the dollar sign. Also, you can use `$` to select a column from a data frame.

`data$scenerio` and `data$allConfigurations` will give what you want.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17518434)

Comment: Why this is not an answer? I do not understand

Comment: I find this more a comment than an answer. The information may be helpful and correct, but you don't provide any context. A tiny addition like: "in R you can access columns in a data frame by using the dollar sign" would already improve it a lot. The OP says he doesn't understand anything, so a little more information is definitely in order here

Comment: Also worth noting the difference between using x$y, ls(x$y) and ls.str(x$y).  ls stands for "list" and str stands for "structure".